# Is it possible to use the same form in two different windows in Extjs4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a table with a button to add a new element and another in the row to edit the element. Those actions shares the same form with the only difference that in edit mode the form is filled. When the user clicks on the button a new window is shown with the form.

The first time that i click the button, for example, to add a new element, works fine. The form is shown. But... if i close the window and i try to edit a user, appears an extrange window without content and an error **"TypeError: b is null"** Is it a problem with the definition of the form? Maybe the form istance is deleted with the window?

I've a form defined in a var:

```
var formPanel =  Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
     extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
     id: 'policyForm',
     ...
```

I have a button in the tbar of the grid to show the window in order to add an user and another button in the row to edit him. This is the handler of the button:

```
handler : function(){
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        layout: 'fit',
        title: 'New Policy',
        items: [formPanel],
        width: 650,
        height: 500,
        id: 'myPolicyWindow'
    }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that those `id`s that you have set in your Panel and Window code are causing you to not be able to reuse the same form in different windows.  You should try to avoid using the `id` property on Ext components, it can cause issues like this one since IDs should be unique.  Use the `itemId` property in conjunction with `Ext.ComponentQuery` to allow for getting references to components without using `Ext.getCmp(compId)`.

Comment: Thank you kevhender. I solved it deleting the id's, defining a custom form and then i create different instances for my windows. I will not use the id property anymore. Either way, if you set an element with the itemId, how can you call it to get the instance?

Comment: You will need to use component queries to navigate through components by relation.  When using `itemId`, use the `#` sign in your component query: `parentCmp.down('#childCmpId')`. See docs at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery.

Comment: Thank you @kevhender. It seems like jquery :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you shouldn't use ids. However, the actual issue is probably what you suspect: the instance of the form is getting destroyed. This is because the default `closeAction` of `Ext.window.Window` is "destroy", which will wipe out any child components as well. Either change `closeAction` to "hide", or create a new instance of the form panel along with the new instance of the window.